# flock with crontab is not working properly

Tags: bash, cron, flock

I have a crontab job, that looks like this:

```
*/5 * * * *  /usr/bin/flock -w 0 /home/partners_perfluence_delivery/cron.lock cd /home/partners_perfluence_delivery && /usr/bin/python3 /home/partners_perfluence_delivery/main.py
```

When I run script `main.py` manually, everything works like a charm. When I'am trying to use crontab job, lock-file is created, but when I am looking for a job with `ps aux | grep main.py` I see nothing in the output as well as requests used in `main.py` are not being made

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: This answer over on Unix & Linux has a similar issue and a good description for others experiencing this issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/603894/flock-command-in-root-cron-wont-execute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`flock` is executing `cd` in a subprocess, then releasing the lock when that completes. If the Python script needs to be run in that directory, it doesn't happen because the directory was only changed in the subprocess.

You should execute `cd` and `python` in the same shell process using `flock -c`.

```
*/5 * * * *  /usr/bin/flock -w 0 /home/partners_perfluence_delivery/cron.lock -c 'cd /home/partners_perfluence_delivery && /usr/bin/python3 /home/partners_perfluence_delivery/main.py'
```

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. Also I faced a strange behavior, that lock isn't removed, given that it should be removed after cd command is executed successfully, isn't that right?

Comment: It should be removed when the python script finishes.

Comment: At least with the versions of `flock` I'm familiar with, you can omit the `sh` argument, because `flock` has a `-c` option that does essentially the same thing.